# Spring cloud contract: defining order of execution of generated tests (more than 10)

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am using spring cloud contract for my project. I have access to both producer and consumer side code.

1) I have created two contracts in producer repo (namely one.yml, two.yml)

2) SCC autogenerated test cases (JUNIT4) on producer side and they passed (because implemetation is already done)

3) I created tests on the consumer side. The tests on consumer side were able to get stubbed responses (from local maven repo) and everything worked as expected.

Now I want to define order of these tests so that one.yml always runs before two.yml. So, I created a directly called scenario, renamed the contracts to 1_one.yml and 2_two.yml and moved them to newly created directory . After this change:

1) Producer side autogenerated tests passed

2) Consumer side tests failed!!!

Could you please explain why this happens and what I need to do to define such ordering of tests? (I have to create 10 yaml contracts and the autogenerated tests should have a pre-defined order)

Answer (score 0):

By adding a prefix you've created scenarios. So after going from state described in contract one, you've managed to get into state two described im contract two. You can read the documentation about scenarios.

If you need them to be in order just order them alphabetically but you can't use a digit at the beginning

Comment: "If you need them to be in order just order them alphabetically". Do you mean I should do the following things 1) rename contracts in ascending alphabatical order 2) Add annotation @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) in my base test class?

Comment: Adding FixedMethodOrder on base class doesn't work because this is not an inherited annotaion. This annotation should be specified on the concrete test classes. There is a bug open since 2012 (https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/559) and some people from community don't want this behaviour.  Does Spring Cloud Contract have a configuration that I can use to add this annotation on generated classes? Or is there any other workaround for us to acheive ordering of tests?

Comment: That's a workaround. In general forcing the ordering of tests is not a common and suggested approach other than for scenarios

Comment: I don't think we ever assumed having more than 9 scenarios. You can create an issue in sc contract repo. In general i think that you're trying to replicate business logic in your contacts which is a mistake. Contracts should be extremely simple and you're trying to setup complex stateful stubs.

Comment: I looked into the Spring cloud contract code and I think creating an issue is not required. I was able to get this working by starting my scenarios like 01_one.yml, 02_two.yml instead of 1_step1, 2_step2 :P .So, I think it just requires documentation update.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thank you.

Comment: could you please tell me where do I need to create PR for documentation?  (I will edit your answer or create a new one before marking this as answered)

Comment: Search for a doc about scenarios either here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc or in any adoc file in the repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192668/discussion-between-aman-and-marcin-grzejszczak).